# Selecionar a linha anterior caso esteja nulo

Tags: oracle

Tenho a seguinte tabela em Oracle e quero preencher valor que estiver nulo na coluna Activity com o valor da linha anterior. Como fazer usando Oracle?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme documentação sobre [LAST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm):

> É uma função analítica. Ele retorna o último valor em um conjunto de
>   valores ordenados. Se o último valor no conjunto for nulo, a função
>   retorna, a NULL menos que você especifique IGNORE NULLS. Esta
>   configuração é útil para densificação de dados. Se você especificar
>   IGNORE NULLS, então LAST_VALUE retorna o valor não-nulo do punho no
>   conjunto, ou NULL se todos os valores são nulos.
>    <sub>*Tradução via google translate*</sub>

Assim aplicando ao seu caso, temos:

```
SELECT t.activity_no
      ,t.locationcode
      ,t.act_start_date
      ,last_value(t.activity ignore NULLS) over(ORDER BY t.activity_no) somecol
  FROM tabela t
```

Fiz um exemplo utilizando o LiveSql da oracle: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E1EDQGXFCBCHG5GLBCEYS75BZ.html

---

Edição para Oracle 9i:

Encontrei uma [resposta](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1769805100346245044) em outro forum aplicado ao *Oracle 9i*,
e fazendo alguns ajustes, e aplicando ao seu caso, ficaria algo assim:

```
SELECT t.activity_no
      ,t.locationcode
      ,t.act_start_date
      ,MAX(CASE
             WHEN t.activity_no = activity_carrydown THEN
              t.activity
           END) over(PARTITION BY activity_carrydown) activity
  FROM (SELECT MAX(CASE
                     WHEN t.activity IS NOT NULL THEN
                      t.activity_no
                   END) over(ORDER BY t.activity_no ASC) activity_carrydown
              ,t.activity_no
              ,t.locationcode
              ,t.act_start_date
              ,t.activity
          FROM tabela t) t
```

Comment: Boa, mas tem um problema estou usando Oracle 9i que nao tem compatibilidade com ignore nulls, alguma outra funcao?

Comment: Editei a resposta, adicionando para o 9i, vê se atende.